# Different types of Vue webpacks , which is suitable to choose if a theme needs to be build in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to build a theme using Vue . which webpack should i need to choose in order to build a ecommerce theme vue app?

Comment: What do you mean by different types of Vue webpacks? Just check out vue-cli. This is the way to go with a Vue app.

Comment: There are different type of Vue webpack available

Comment: For exg - $ vue init webpack-simple my-project

Comment: I hope you are using Vue-CLI 3 - then you can simply run `vue create hello-world` and it will ask you some questions and then build the correct Webpack.

Comment: can you share reference link ?